# Sorting the output of the Windows tree command?

Tags: windows, command-line, unix, tree

I typically use `bash` in MSYS2 on Windows, however, I have to inspect a massive network share (on which the MSYS2 version of `tree` chokes - as in, takes forever), and so I'm forced to use the Windows tools.

So, basically, the output of the `tree` command looks like this:

```
C:\Users\me\Videos>tree /f .
Folder PATH listing for volume Windows
Volume serial number is 6789-B2DA
C:\USERS\ME\VIDEOS
│   my_test.avi
│
├───Captures
├───Debut
├───kdenlive-renderqueue
├───Logitech
│   └───LogiCapture
│           2020-11-24_09-19-44.jpg
│
├───test
│       test.mlt
│
├───test1
│       test1.mlt
│
└───titles
```

Here the output even looks kind of sorted, but on the massive network shares I have to inspect, I've seen that there is no sorting, as [Windows "tree" command sorts randomly](https://superuser.com/questions/652948/windows-tree-command-sorts-randomly) confirms.

So, by using:

```
powershell "tree /f . | tee C:\Users\me\mylist.txt"
```

... I can obtain the listing in text file with a UCS-2 BE BOM encoding - and using Notepad++, I can convert this file to UTF-8.

So, I was wondering - is there some sort of a program/script, in either DOS/Windows world, or bash/Unix world, that can parse such an output from a `tree` command, and provide a sorted ouptut of the same? (I'm interested in alphabetic order of file/directory name, ascending, directories first, then files).

Comment: related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90115/convert-output-of-tree-command-to-json-format

Answer (score 2):

You could try 'dir' from the Command Line instead of Powershell.

```
dir /s /b
```

- /s include subdir
- /b bare (shows file/folder only)

or add parameter /o:g   (sort, directories first)

```
dir /s /b /o:g
```

Comment: Thanks - pretty neat solution, goes fast on network share, I'm happy with output, there's just one problem: if I use just `dir /s /b /o:g .` in cmd, all goes fine; if I use it in `powershell "dir /s /b /o:g . | tee C:\Users\me\mylist.txt"`, then I get an error: "`Get-ChildItem : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '/o:g'`". Any ideas how to get that working?

Answer (score 0):

I made a Windows bat file, including PowerShell commands, that creates a very similar formatted output to the tree command, but sorted.  Just copy this code as maketreehere.bat (can use notepad and change the extension) in the folder you want to have analyzed, and run from CMD or double click from Windows Explorer.  Hope it helps others!

```
@echo off
title Make Tree Script by Zentico
chcp 65001

echo Reading folder structure for files and directories.
dir /b /s /a-d > "tree_raw_f.txt"
dir /b /s /ad > "tree_raw_d.txt"

echo Eliminating current path and adding tags.
REM Replace backslashes (\) in CURRENT_PATH with escaped backslash
set "CURRENT_PATH=%CD:\=\\%"

powershell -Command "(gc tree_raw_f.txt -encoding UTF8 | Where-Object {$_ -notmatch 'tree_raw_f.txt'}) -replace '^(.*\\)(.*)$', '${1}00001$2' -replace '%CURRENT_PATH%\\', '' | Out-File -encoding UTF8 tree_noroot_f.txt"
powershell -Command "(gc tree_raw_d.txt -encoding UTF8 | ForEach-Object {$_ + '\00000'}) -replace '%CURRENT_PATH%\\', '' | Out-File -encoding UTF8 tree_noroot_d.txt"

echo Merging and sorting.
powershell -Command "(gc tree_noroot_f.txt, tree_noroot_d.txt -encoding UTF8 | Sort-Object) | Out-File -encoding UTF8 tree_sorted.txt"

echo Eliminating tags and adding formatting.
REM Get the current date in the format YYMMDD
set CURRENT_DATE=%date:~12,2%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%

powershell -Command "(gc tree_sorted.txt -encoding UTF8) -replace '00001', '' -replace '([^\\]+)\\00000', '├───$1:' -replace '(.*?)\\', '│   ' | Out-File -encoding UTF8 %CURRENT_DATE%_tree.txt"

echo Cleanup.
REM Delete intermediate files
del tree_raw_f.txt tree_raw_d.txt tree_noroot_f.txt tree_noroot_d.txt tree_sorted.txt

REM End and wait for keypress
pause
```